# On algebraic morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question

Let given schemes $Y\subset X$ and $Z$, where $Y$ is closed subscheme of $X$. Assume that for some morphism $f:Y\to Z$, $Z = [f(Y)]$ (where [] means closure in $Z$). Is it true that there exists scheme $V :Z\subset V$ (where $Z$ is closed subscheme of $V$), not empty open subscheme $U\subset X$ and morphism $f':U\to V$ such that $f'|_{U\cap Y} = f|_{U\cap Y}$?

Comment: No. Let $f:Y\to Z=\mathbb P^2$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb P^2$ at a point, embedded in some projective space $X=\mathbb P^n$ and let $f:Y\to Z=\mathbb P^2$ be the blow-up. The map $f$ does not extend to $\mathbb P^n$.

Comment: Please give precise assumptions. What does $Y\subset X$ mean? Are your schemes separated?

Comment: Is it now clear?

Comment: The answer to the current question is yes because $U$ can be empty. Just checking -- does "let we know that..." mean "Assume that..."?

Comment: Ok. Motivation for this question is next: if $X, Y, Z$ are affine algebraical varieties, then we can assume that for some $n, k$, $Y\subset X\subset\mathbb{A}^n$, $Z\subset\mathbb{A}^k$ and $(f_1, \ldots, f_k)|_Y = f$, where $f_i\in\mathbb{K}[\mathbb{A}^n]$. So $f' = (f_i), V = \mathbb{A}^k$ are suitible

Comment: I think answer to your question is "yes" if $X, Y, Z$ are quasi   affine varieties, but can we do this for general schemes (with axiomatic defenition of morphisms)?